# Why User Logs In But is Not Authenticating Sporadically In Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

So I have a weird bug that I can't seem to track down. I'm using firebase functions on the backend and SwiftUI. My login flow goes like this:

User logs in from loginView. The loginView then uses a callback to pass a user to move on to the next View after a user logs in.

After this a user is passed to the View where it calls the firebase functions.

The problem is that every once in a while a user fails authentication. This doesn't happen every time and usually happens when a user has not logged in for 12 hours or more. I thought it may have been a race condition at first but after further investigation decided that it wasn't given the fact that it's using a callback.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? If so is there any way to fix this?

I have tried making my firebase function stay warm by setting minimum instances to 1 because I initially thought it may be a cold start issue but this hasn't helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

On the frontend the code is pulling like so:

```
        FirebaseAuthService().signIn(email: email, password: password) { result, error in
        if (error?.occurred) != nil {
            self.errorMessage = error!.details
            self.state = .failed
            self.showErrorAlert = true
            return
        }
        
        if (localAuthEnabled) {
          ...... This piece of code works

        FirebaseFirestoreService().fetchUser(userID: result?.user.uid ?? "", completion: { user, error 

               ....... This piece of code works.
            }
        })
    }
```

User is then taken to another view AFTER logging in

This view pulls from 5 or so firebase functions asynchronously (but the user is already logged in by this point). The function that it fails at is as follows

```
   self.function.httpsCallable("api-report").call() { (result, error) in
       ... It is at times it gives me an auth error inside of this function.
           
  }
```

I am using this to log out whenever a user put the app in the background or hits the log out button:

```
    func signOut() -> Bool {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.session = nil
        return true
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Error signing out: %@", err)
        return false
    }
}
```

on the backend the report call does the following with the report. This is a large function. I have only added the call to show whats going on.

```
exports.handler = async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        console.log("report error context");
        console.log(context);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'by authenticated users.', 'User must be authenticated');
    }
}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Great to see a google employee here. I can't include all code because its pulling sensitive information but. I will include the gist of what Im trying to achieve. Give me a few minutes to get it together.

Comment: Please check the link, as the best way to get an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is to start from scratch. I know that can be annoying, but it's the most likely way you'll get it in the shape that we can help (and is also a common way to find the problem yourself).

Comment: I think I may have done that to an extent. I am showing the calls. The login and the sign out along with the api call. This does not happen every time so I am not really sure whats causing it. It only happens maybe 2 times a day. But its very annoying :)

Comment: Oh and wait. Let me find the exact error thats being thrown so I can show you what it is saying

Comment: The status code is:  Function execution took 7 ms, finished with status code: 400
Function execution took 7 ms, finished with status code: 400.     The Error is: Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=9 "The function must be called by authenticated users." UserInfo={details=User must be authenticated, NSLocalizedDescription=The function must be called by authenticated users.} occurred for user: XXXX@XXX.com

Comment: After this they logged in again one second later and their log in worked, Im not sure if its due to the cold start or what

Comment: This happens maybe once or twice a day randomly.

Comment: It seems the call may be happening just as/after the user is logged out, or their token is being refreshed. If it's the token being refreshed, the client should just retry the call in cases such as this.

Comment: I was thinking along them lines. My partner and I had been discussing that but didn’t wanna make it feel too hacky. Another thang we were thinking was to maybe delay the call for a half second or so to give the backend a chance to update. But thank you so much for your confirmation of this. We will implement this right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the call to your backend may be happening just as/after the user is logged out, or their token is being refreshed. If it's the token being refreshed, the client should just retry the call in cases such as this.

You could also check whether the token is about to expire, and force a refresh  when that is the case, or delay calling the Cloud Function until the token has refreshed.